# Hibernate @DynamicUpdate - Concurrency

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, concurrency

We have a table say 'A' in our system, this system is replicated in several servers to high availability, this happends on the same time:

1. One transaction (t1) is processed on Server 1 which loads entity "A" and update it with a new value to column "xxx".
2. Previuous of update of point 1, another transaction (t2) is processed on Server 2 which loads the same entity "A" to update column "yyy", then t1 is commited, and then t2 is commited (but this update it does with the old value of "xxx" (This generates inconsistencies in the database)

I understand that this could be solved with the annotation @DynamicUpdate.
I would like to know your suggestion about it.
Than you everyone!!

Comment: `@DynamicUpdate` wouldn't resolve the race condition.

Comment: Yep, i know but if update is only to the related columns maybe resolve my problem or no?